# Transaction not mined error when deploying to quorum maker server

Tags: web3js, truffle, nodejs, truffle-migration, quorum

I get the following error when attempting to deploy my zeppelin erc20 token to a quorum server(used quorum maker).

````````
    (master) $ node migrations/2_proj.js
``````` transactionHash 0xcd2c34e35564a3a50557563a8ff512ea55fda9cefbf5ef927678d2e7dbb3b9ee
``````` Error: Transaction was not mined within750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
    at /Users/.../code/proj/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:390:42
    at <anonymous>
(node:49162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction was not mined within750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
    at /Users/.../code/proj/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:390:42
    at <anonymous>
(node:49162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:49162) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
````````

This is the code used to deploy:

``````````
var Web3 = require('web3')
var TruffleConfig = require('../truffle')

let deployToken = async function() {
const config = TruffleConfig.networks['ma1Staging']
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://' + config.host + ':' + config.port))

let contractJson = require('../build/contracts/' + 'token.sol'.replace('.sol', '.json'))
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractJson.abi)
await contract.deploy({
    data: contractJson.bytecode,
}).send({
    from: config.from,
    gas: 3000000,
    gasPrice: '0',
}).on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('````````error', error)
}).on('transactionHash', (transactionHash) => {
    console.log('````````transactionHash', transactionHash)
}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
    console.log('````````receipt', receipt) // contains the new contract address
}).on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
    console.log('````````confirmationNumber, receipt', confirmationNumber, receipt)
})
console.log('`````````migration done')
}
deployToken()
module.exports = deployToken
``````````

To run it I use node from the command line.

This is my sol file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Mintable.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol";

/**
@title token
*/
contract tokenName is ERC20Mintable, ERC20Burnable {
    string public name = "tokenName";
    string public symbol = "tokenName";
    uint public decimals = 18;
}
```

I used truffle to build my contract.

Comment: Hi @bj973301 , how did you resolve this please?